# How to find theta bound without using substitution method: proof by induction?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o, divide-and-conquer

k is a positive constant and 1 ≤ z < m:

[image]

How can I solve this using induction in order to prove a Theta bound for T(m, n). But I cannot use substitution method. Im not allowed.
which one is correct? 
T(m, n) = Θ(mn), T(m, n) = Θ(m^2n^2)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to math.stackexchange.com